# How to have Django templates display slugs

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Hi guys i am new to django...i been watching youtube videos and reading books on Django but  am still struggling with templates. I am working on a ecommerce project and i would love a bit of help with templates. So i want my template to display a list of categories as links on a sidebar. I have defined a slug field in my category models and i have managed to map a url...but i am still not getting a list of categories on my index page sidebar.

This is my url pattern and this is working perfect. When i click 127.0.0.1.000/food  it's working (food is a category)

```
  path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.category, name='category'),
```

the view function

```
def category(request, category_slug):
    """Defines category views"""
    categories= get_object_or_404(Category, slug= category_slug)
    context = {'categories': categories}
    return render(request, "categories_list.html", context)
```

This is the categories_list.html template that i need help with

```
<h3> Shop by Category </h3>
    {% if category in categories %}
    <li>
          <a href ="{{category.slug}}"> {{category.name}}</a>
    </li>
{% endif %}
```

My wish is to have the categories displayed on the sidebar of my index page as links. I have used `{% include 'category_list.html' %}` on my index page template, and its only displaying the Shop by Category heading instead of the categories when i am on the index page. I have tried the for loop in my template but if didn't work, it kept on saying category object not iterable...so i ended up using the if statement. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

get_object_or_404() method returns single instance or None if it is not found.
You can't iterate that way on object.

Try next

View

```
def category(request, slug):
    """Defines category views."""
    return render(request, 'categories_list.html', {'category': get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)})
```

Template

```
{{ category.slug }}
```

Comment: Thanks mate i followed your advice but unfortunately it did not work....your code kind of resembles mine except mine is slightly long. The problem is on the template i think. Even when i use `categories= Category.objects.get(slug= slug) or categories= Category.objects.all(slug=slug` nothing is working.

Comment: Difference is that you were doing if category in categories, it will not work. Can you show your model? Does it have property slug? Maybe you call it another way.

Comment: That is why i used the if statement....the if statement did not return any errors like the for loop. i just want my categories to be displayed on my sidebar as url links that can be clicked and change the address from 127.0.000 to 127.0.000/electronics for example

Comment: Here is my category model,.. `class Category(models.Model): name= models.CharField(max_length=100) slug= models.SlugField(max_length= 100, unique= True) class Meta: ordering = ('name',) verbose_name= 'category' verbose_name_plural= 'categories' def __str__(self): return self.name def get_absolute_url(self): return reverse('category', kwargs={'category_slug': self.slug}) `...i just added the get_absolute_url and i called it the template still nothing. The for loop didnt work it kept saying cannot iterate over object

Comment: what {{ category }} displays?