# getting url slug django

Tags: python, django, url, slug

i am wanna get url slug to show selected category by user on breadcumb. how can i get it? i found only wordpress and php solves.

*template*

```
<div class="breadcumb_area bg-img" style="background-image: url({% static 'img/bg-img/breadcumb.jpg' %});">
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="page-title text-center">
                    <h2>dresses</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have not added the full code of breadcump.html. yet I can suggest you achieve it. we could help you much better if you would post full code.

To store slug, You can use django built-in `SlugField` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#slugfield

You can generate slug value from title or whatever you want using `slugify` method:
`from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify`

I think this post will help you much more in this case.

[How do I create a slug in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837828/how-do-i-create-a-slug-in-django)

and to render the slug url on django template

The post is very accurate solution: [How to have Django templates display slugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61634473/how-to-have-django-templates-display-slugs)

****Note: Please avoid posting such common problems that already been answered by someone before****